# Using ant with nitrous.io

Tags: nitrousio

I'm trying to use ant with nitrous to build my application. However, due to lack of sudo privileges, I can't install ant. Is there a way to circumvent this?

### sudo apt-get -u install ant

### WARNING: sudo access is not available; running without sudo.

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Answer (score 2):

If your Nitrous box supports Autoparts (newer ones do), you can just type `parts install ant`.

If not, follow the directions at http://blog.nitrous.io/2013/09/18/introducing-autoparts-for-nitrous-io.html to install Autoparts, and then install ant with it.